# I have started nexus server in cmd and it's started, but when I trying to access nexus through web via (http://localhost:8081/nexus )it's not working

Tags: devops, nexus

**2023-07-03 18:32:45,463+0530 ERROR [jetty-main-1]  org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap - Failed to initialize
jvm 1    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nexus work directory already in use: C:\Program Files\sonatype-work\nexus**
jvm 1    |      at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:200)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap.contextInitialized(WebappBootstrap.java:117)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1073)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1002)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:247)
jvm 1    | 2023-07-03 18:32:45,479+0530 WARN  [jetty-main-1]  org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2be7d929{Nexus Repository Manager 2.15.1-02,/nexus,file:///C:/Program%20Files/nexus-2.15.1-02/nexus/,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Program Files\nexus-2.15.1-02/nexus}
jvm 1    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nexus work directory already in use: C:\Program Files\sonatype-work\nexus
jvm 1    |      at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:200)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap.contextInitialized(WebappBootstrap.java:117)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1073)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1002)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:247)
jvm 1    | 2023-07-03 18:32:45,495+0530 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - node0 Stopped scavenging
jvm 1    | 2023-07-03 18:32:45,517+0530 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Running
jvm 1    | 2023-07-03 18:32:45,517+0530 ERROR [WrapperListener_start_runner]  org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Start failed
jvm 1    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nexus work directory already in use: C:\Program Files\sonatype-work\nexus
jvm 1    |      at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:200)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap.contextInitialized(WebappBootstrap.java:117)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1073)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1002)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:247)
jvm 1    | 2023-07-03 18:32:45,533+0530 ERROR [WrapperListener_start_runner]  org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jsw.JswLauncher - Failed to start
jvm 1    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nexus work directory already in use: C:\Program Files\sonatype-work\nexus
jvm 1    |      at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:200)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap.contextInitialized(WebappBootstrap.java:117)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1073)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1002)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:247)
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped

I tried all possible ways but no use, can anyone help on this issue please ?